# Nhibernate criteria error

Tags: nhibernate

this code

```
        public IList<Patient> GetByMRNNameDOB(Patient patient)
    {
        using (ISession session = SessionManager.Current.OpenSession())
        {
            ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Patient))
                .Add(Expression.Disjunction()
                         .Add(Expression.Eq("patient.MedicalRecordNumber", patient.MedicalRecordNumber))
                         .Add(Expression.Conjunction()
                                  .Add(Expression.Eq("patient.FirstName", patient.FirstName))
                                  .Add(Expression.Eq("patient.LastName", patient.LastName))
                                  .Add(Expression.Eq("patient.Birthday", patient.Birthday))));

            return criteria.List<Patient>();
        }
    }
```

throws an error:

> Could not resolve property: patient of:
>   SolutionConsultants.WebScreening.Entities.Patients.Patient
>
> Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Patient))
    .Add(Expression.Disjunction()
                     .Add(Expression.Eq("MedicalRecordNumber", 
                                        patient.MedicalRecordNumber))
                     .Add(Expression.Conjunction()
                              .Add(Expression.Eq("FirstName", patient.FirstName))
                              .Add(Expression.Eq("LastName", patient.LastName))
                              .Add(Expression.Eq("Birthday", patient.Birthday))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you had in mind, but probably `patient` is just an alias that you wanted to use for the query, if that's the case you can simply include it in the `CreateCriteria` method like so (*not tested*, I'm away from my computer):

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Patient), "patient");
...
```

Hope it helps!